# Blackberry Bold 9930 Simulator Page change Error Phonegap

Tags: jquery, forms, blackberry, cordova

I have got a phonegap application which consists of one page with transitions between different forms within the page. I have compiled and tested the application on a few blackberry devices and it works perfectly. However when I test on either the 9930 simulator of the bold 9930 it refuses to change form it just white screens and and rerenders.

Answer (score 0):

It seemed to have something to do with the alerts i had in my javascript it is now working perfectly.

I am onto inserting notifications into the statusbar